# Debian: auto loading encrypted volumes

Tags: linux, debian

I have a Debian Jessie 8.2. I set up encrypted volumes for root and swap.
At boot time I get:

```
Loading, please wait...
[    3.1117072] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode found
[    3.1117142] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
  One or more specified logical volumes(s) not found.
Unable to find LVM volume group/root_crypt
  One or more specified logicial volume(s) not found.
Unable to find LVM volume group/swap_crypt  
  Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
  Found volume group "group" using metadata type lvm2
  3 logicial volume(s) in group "group" now active
Please unlock disk group-root_crypt:
```

which looks fine I guess. Is there any way to get these encrypted drives auto loaded at boot time without having to type passwords in?

Comment: Take a look http://madduck.net/docs/cryptdisk/ in the "using key files" section